# Pushing to a Git repository on an NFS share fails

Tags: git, ssh, nfs

We currently have our Git repositories on the local disk. They are shared by groups and accessed over SSH (with git-shell).

Because of space issues, we now want to move the repositories to an NFS share on a NAS. I've been experimenting with this, and have run into a weird issue. A fresh (and bare) repository with exactly the same permissions can be cloned fine, but pushing changes (touch foo && git add foo && git commit && git push origin master) fails with the error "Couldn't set refs/heads/master" and "failed to write".

Now, if I repeat this scenario on the local disk, refs/heads/master becomes owned by whatever user pushed. Conversely, on the NFS share, if I change its owner to the user who is trying to push, no error is thrown. However, in both cases, the user is a member of a the group that owns the entire repository and has group write permission. Additionally, if I just log in using SSH as a user who is a member of this group, I can touch refs/heads/master (as is to be expected), both on the NFS share and the local disk.

Consequently, I am at a loss here. I have no idea why a different file owner would cause the push to fail, seeing as how the group permissions allow the user to overwrite refs/heads/master. Moreover, even with a chmod 777 on that file, the push fails unless I chown the file.

If anyone can shed some light on this weirdness, I'll be most grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Ah, darn. The NAS is doing weird things to permissions, setting the sticky bit on all directories. This explains the behavior. An additional chmod solved the problem.

Comment: What exactly was the additional chmod that fixed the problem?

Comment: In my repository initialization script, I use `chmod -R 660 . &&       find -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;` but your mileage may vary ...

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick for me. I get this error when trying to commit in a repo on an NFS share of a remote machine which I access vis SSHFS (since the remote machine doesn't have git installed). Directories were sticky, but `chmod` didn't help. I own all the files/directories and have write permission to all of them.

Comment: Turns out my issue was that [sshfs does not by default support renaming](http://dragffy.com/blog/posts/using-sshfs-with-bazaar-bzr-or-git) which is required for git operations.

Comment: The link given by @kynan is dead, but the key point is to use sshfs with option -oworkaround=rename as mentioned [here](http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/07/08/git-over-sshfs).