# Master failed to write error while pushing commit

Tags: git

I have a git repository on a company network drive and had no problem pulling from it. However, i wasn't able to push any commits into it, though I had a few good luck but recently I couldn't get anything in it. The error was:

> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe push "origin" master:master error:
>   Couldn't set refs/heads/master To //software/pdd.git/ ! [remote
>   rejected] master -> master (failed to write) error: failed to push
>   some refs to '//software/pdd.git/' Done

I suspect that it got to with the `master` file. On Windows, it shows that I might have been put into a network group that does not allow me to do modify but was able to read, write and execute.

My question is: If i was able to push a few times before, this file permission thing shouldm't be a hassle to me. If it, indeed, that I don't have enough privillage to modify, is there a workaround?

PS: The company is reluctant to change my network group to another, which would enable me to modify files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the question "[Pushing to a Git repository on an NFS share fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675587/pushing-to-a-git-repository-on-an-nfs-share-fails)":

> The NAS is doing weird things to permissions, setting the sticky bit on all directories. This explains the behavior. An additional `chmod` solved the problem.

That means this is a permission issue on the target (remote) side, as illustrated in "[Git issues after upgrading to osx Lion](http://www.sargas.com/2011/07/git-issues-after-upgrading-to-osx-lion/)":

> there was an odd permission for everyone as ‘custom’. I updated this to be ‘Read & Write’ and the commit was finally successful.

As a "workaound", See this [Error section](http://www.vaddina.com/index.php?title=GIT#Errors):

> I just deleted my bare repository and created a brand new one and pushed my changes over there. And everything works again.

Comment: It seeems like I didn't elaborate enough on the IT side on how they wouldn't change my privillages due to my company contract. Thanks for the advice though

Comment: @freonix: so you need to get in touch with the IT support team and see how the privileges can be compatible with your situation without compromising their policy.

Comment: Gladly would but my superior said he has conveyed the message but doesn't seem to get through the high ups.

Comment: @freonix: you could at least ask them to recreate a bare repo, and see if the issue persists when pushing to that *new* remote.

Comment: I'd tried this morning with my colleagues whether they could push into bare repo that I made. It seems that they could push as well, getting the same error, and they have more privillages then me. What gives..

Comment: @freonix: hence the importance of re-creating a *new* bare repo, since they might have been a change in the ACL on the remote side.

Comment: If I do that, my colleagues wont be able to access as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3085/discussion-between-freonix-and-vonc)

Comment: @freonix: you can add as many remote as you want. That won't impact your colleagues. They can keep pushing to the original remote, while testing if they can push to the new one.