# How do I set up a remote repo on a network drive?

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up a repo on our network drive at work. This repo will act as a remote that everyone else will push to/pull from, so I create a folder on the network drive where the repo will be:

```
cd path/to/remote
mkdir ourGit
cd ourGit
git init --bare
```

On my local machine, I already have a working tree that I want to push to the remote.

```
git remote add origin path/to/remote
git push -u origin master
```

The initial push is successful.

Then on a coworker's machine, I clone the repo and make a commit.

```
git clone path/to/remote newFolderName
...make some changes...
git add --all
git commit -m "-made some changes"
```

Everything works fine up to this point, but when I try to push the local changes from my coworker's machine to the upstream remote, I get this error.

```
git push
...
remote: error: couldn't set refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Probably a permissions problem on the remote -- if your coworker does not have write permission to the repo (becuase it was created/ownd by you?) she'll get that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was Windows permissions on the network drive. The creator of the repo has to allow access to everyone who will use it.

On the network drive, create the repository folder, right click on it, go to properties.

Security > Permissions > Allow full control

Answer (score 1):

The permission issue seems confirmed.

For instance, a [remote accessed through NAS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4675841/6309) has [sticky bits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79395/7490) why get in the way.

See "[How do I share a Git repository with multiple users on a machine?](https://serverfault.com/a/27040/783)".
You have the choice between:

- `chmod -R`
- `setfacl -R`